# Qual é o inverso de :visible no jQuery?

Tags: jquery, seletores

O Seletor `:visible` no jQuery serve para procurar por um elemento quando o mesmo é visível.

Exemplo:

```
$(this).find('li:visible').addClass('color-red');
```

Porém, ao tentar procurar elementos invisíveis, não temos o seletor `:invisible`

```
 $(':invisible') // Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: invisible
```

- Qual é o inverso de `:visible` no jQuery?
- E como eu poderia criar a expressão `:invisible` dentro do próprio jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podes usar [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/), o [pseudo `:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) ou o [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) assim:

```
$('div:hidden').addClass('color-red');
// ou
$('div:not(:visible)').addClass('color-red');
// ou
$('div').not(':visible').addClass('color-red');
```

Exemplo com `:hidden`: http://jsfiddle.net/68431qjn/
Exemplo com `:not(:visible)`: http://jsfiddle.net/68431qjn/3/
Exemplo com `.not(':visible')`: http://jsfiddle.net/68431qjn/1/

Comment: Pode também usar o [`$('div:not(:visible)')`](http://jsfiddle.net/68431qjn/2/).

Comment: @KaduAmaral bem visto! juntei esse também.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção!

Comment: Lembrando que o .not(':visible') e :hidden não são exatamente a mesma coisa, veja a documentação jQuery para ver a diferença

Comment: O melhor teste a se fazer é : `$('body').hide().is(':visible')`. Pra mim, retornou `true`. Então o `:hidden` auxiliou no meu caso :)

Comment: Ou ainda podemos fazer: `$('div').filter(':not(:visible)')`. Era assim que eu estava usando, mas perguntei pra saber se tinha algum jeito mais simples

Comment: @WallaceMaxters nesse caso ai ele vai pegar todas as `divs` existente e depois filtra-las para ver qual não está visível, é uma grande execução de códigos desnecessários. Das formas listadas a que eu recomendo é `$('div:hidden')`, simples e direto. O [exemplo que eu dei](http://jsfiddle.net/68431qjn/2/) também é uma escrita desnecessárias estaria fazendo `($bool == TRUE && $bool != FALSE)` em vez de apenas `($bool)`.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que seja `hidden`.

Exemplo:

```
$(this).find('li:hidden').addClass('color-red');
```

https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/